# Does initializing one value in a multi-dimension array initialize the rest of the array?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array

A while ago, it was pointed out to me that initializing a value in a (single-dimensional) array also initializes the rest of the array with 0s. That is,

```
int array[5] = { 1 };
```

... is effectively the same as:

```
int array[5] = { 1, 0, 0, 0, 0 };
```

Is the same true for multi-dimensional arrays? Consider this code:

```
double matrix[5][5] = { { 1.0 } };
```

If `matrix[0][0]` is the only assigned value, is the rest garbage (left-overs in memory), or is the rest filled with `0.0`?

One may say that I could simply iterate over the values to see for myself, but I am afraid that I could get lucky and always have `matrix` occupy "empty" memory (where the bits are all 0) which could possibly lead me to the wrong conclusion.

Comment: Just think of a 2D array as an array of array, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's the same with multidimensional arrays. From the C11 draft N1570, $6.7.9.10:

> - if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
> - if it has arithmetic type, it is **initialized to (positive or unsigned) zero**;
> - if it is an aggregate, every member is **initialized (recursively) according to these rules [above]**,
>       and any padding is initialized to zero bits;

So all members of the array are guaranteed to be initialized to zero.

Comment: Thank you for a non-heuristic answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to the C Standard

> 19 The initialization shall occur in initializer list order, each
>   initializer provided for a particular subobject overriding any
>   previously listed initializer for the same subobject;151) **all
>   subobjects that are not initialized explicitly shall be initialized
>   implicitly the same as objects that have static storage duration.**

and

10 If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate. **If an object that has static or thread storage duration is not initialized explicitly, then:**

> — if it has pointer type, it is initialized to a null pointer;
>
> — if it has arithmetic type, it is initialized to (positive or
>   unsigned) zero;
>
> — if it is an aggregate, every member is initialized (recursively)
>   according to these rules, and any padding is initialized to zero bits;
>
> — if it is a union, the first named member is initialized
>   (recursively) according to these rules, and any padding is initialized
>   to zero bits;

Thus in this declaration

```
double matrix[5][5] = { { 1.0 } };
```

the first element of the array is initialized by `1.0` and all other are initialized by zero.

You can selectively initialize some elements with an explicitly specified value as for example

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    double matrix[5][5] = { { [0] = 1.0, [4] = 1.0 }, { [2] = 2.0, [3] = 2.0 }, [4] = { 5, 5, 5, 5, 5 } };

    for ( size_t i = 0; i < 5; i++ )
    {
        for ( int j = 0; j < 5; j++ ) printf( "%lf ", matrix[i][j] );
        printf( "\n" );
    }        

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
1.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 2.000000 2.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000 
5.000000 5.000000 5.000000 5.000000 5.000000
```

Comment: Ah, I never knew about selectively initializing elements. Very cool!